# Можно ли применять монады в node.js?

Tags: node.js

Вот собственно мне в голову пришла мысль. Зачем писать вот так

```
fs.readdir(dir_name, function (err, folders) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("can not dir folders");
    }
    folders.forEach(function (folders, index) {
        folder = dir_name + "/" + folders;
        fs.readdir(folder, function (err, file) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("can not dir folder");
            }
            file.forEach(function (f, index) {
                file_name = "/" + folders + "/" + f;
                console.log(file_name);

                if (path_name == file_name) {
                    path_name = file_name;
                    fs.readFile(dir_name + path_name, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("can not read file");
                        } else {
                            res.writeHead(200, {
                                'Content-Type': contentType(path_name)
                            });
                            res.write(data);
                            res.end();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

если можно например чтение папок обернуть в функцию readFile(), перебор массива в функцию each(). Вот что у меня получилось

```
var fs=require("fs");
var http=require("http");
var dir=__dirname+"/public";

function readDir(dir) {
    console.log("function readDir has require");
    fs.readdir(dir,function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("can not dir folders");
        }
        //console.log(data);-->[ 'css', 'html', 'icons', 'js' ]
        return data;
    });
}
function each(folders,dir) {
    console.log("function each has require");
    console.log(folders);
    var folder;
    folders.forEach(function (data,i) {
        folder=dir+"/"+data;
        console.log(folder);
        return folder;
    });
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var bind=function (temp,continuation) {
        return continuation(temp);
    };
    var final=bind(readDir(dir),function(rezult){
        console.log(rezult);//-->undefined
        /*return bind(each(rezult,dir),function(rezult1) {
            console.log(rezult1);
        });*/
    });
}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
console.log("server has started");
```

если ли я в чем то не прав поправте меня. И почему undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравните ваш кусок кода и мой, в чем различия?

```
function readDir(dir, callback) {
    console.log("function readDir has require");
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("can not dir folders");
        }
        callback(data);
    });
}
function each(folders, dir, callback) {
    console.log("function each has require");
    console.log(folders);
    var folder;
    folders.forEach(function (data) {
        folder=dir+"/"+data;
        console.log(folder);

        callback(folder);
    });
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    readDir(dir, function(fldrs) {
        each(fldrs, dir, function(folder) {
            console.log(folder);
        });
    });

}).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
console.log("server has started");
```

Answer (score 3):

return тут не уместен. lampa хотел сказать что результат работы асинхронной функции надо передавать в коллбек и обрабатывать уже в нем. В вашем варианте пока функция fs.readdir(....) читает директорию, функция readDir() уже завершила свою работу не доходя до return-a (то есть вернула undefined).

Comment: а понятно чтение занимает определенное время

Comment: а если передать условие if(datе){}. Данные прочитались, и только тогда передовать на выполнение.. Я думаю у меня получиться? И что за Кисы?

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast Обратите внимание на 20-ое видео. Из 12 стульев Киса Воробьянинов. Он там кричал: 'торг тут не уместен!'

Comment: @little_boy не чтение занимает определенное время, а метод readdir - асинхронный. пример:

    setTimeout(myfunct,0); //время "не занимает" но асинхронна.